# Make div clickable/dragable to have it control the scroll of the page? (JSFiddle Included)

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I want to make #scrollbox clickable/dragable within #overview, and have it control the scroll position of the document.

http://jsfiddle.net/mgJf2/1/

Thanks all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a [jQuery plugin](http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/) which has the exact functionality that you are looking for.

Comment: Hrrm, seems like a bit of overkill, I already have most of this functionality built with a few lines of javascript. I'm just looking to make the box drag-able within a div and collect the resulting data.

Comment: Yeah, the thing is is that the last bit of functionality you need is the most difficult functionality of a draggable scrollbar. If you're sure you want to, [this](http://elouai.com/javascript-drag-and-drop.php) might help with the clickalbe/draggable.